# How do I specify conditional dependencies based on target framework in NuGet?

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I am building a NuGet package that references the Microsoft CommonServiceLocator assembly.

There are two versions of the Microsoft CommonServiceLocator out there:

- [CommonServiceLocator](http://nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator) - targets the full .NET framework and is referenced by the Microsoft EnterpriseLibrary components.
- [Portable.CommonServiceLocator](http://nuget.org/packages/Portable.CommonServiceLocator) - contains both the full version of CommonServiceLocator and [the recently released Portable Class Library version](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/releases/view/17694).

My project is a Portable Class Library but, because it's sometimes used with Enterprise Library, I need to sort of "conditionally" reference the portable version so there's no conflict.

- If the target framework is full .NET 4.0/4.5, use the original CommonServiceLocator package so people can also use the Enterprise Library bits (which also reference the CommonServiceLocator package).
- If the target framework is portable (or anything else) use the Portable.CommonServiceLocator package.

[I see the new "group" feature in the NuGet docs showing how to specify dependencies in your .nuspec file](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Specifying_Dependencies) and I think that will do what I want, but I'm not sure how to test it.

**Here's what I *think* I need to do and I'm hoping someone can validate my approach or point me in the right direction:**

```xml
<dependencies>
  <group>
    <!-- Always include regardless of target framework -->
    <dependency id="Autofac" />
  </group>
  <group targetFramework="net40">
    <!-- Also include the full CSL if it's full framework -->
    <dependency id="CommonServiceLocator" />
  </group>
  <group targetFramework="portable-win+sl50+wp8">
    <!-- Otherwise include the Portable CSL -->
    <dependency id="Portable.CommonServiceLocator" />
  </group>
</dependencies>
```

Specifically...

- **Is my `targetFramework` syntax right?** I can't find any examples, so I don't know if the `+` delimited mechanism is right or if it should be comma-delimited.
- **Will the default group work?** That group with the unspecified target framework - will that always be included or do I need to copy/paste it in every group?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, that's pretty much correct. Details on portable framework names can be found here http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Framework_Names

One more thing I found, since win+sl50+wp8 by default includes net45 you might want to include it so that this dependency group gets installed.

Comment: If it's full net45, I want it to use the CommonServiceLocator, not the portable, so would I use this? targetFramework="net40+net45"

Comment: nope, not required and it would work fine and use <group targetFramework="net40">
when installing on a project targeting net4.5 as it would rank the exact match higher than the portable library. and just specifying net40 would work as "When NuGet installs a package that has multiple assembly versions, it tries to match the framework name of the assembly with the target framework of the project. If a match is not found, NuGet copies the assembly that's for the highest version that is less than or equal to the project's target framework"

Comment: Then it sounds like I actually do want to leave out the net45 reference and the rest of things should just fall into place. Perfect! Thanks!